Which thread will handle `int 3` SIGTRAP in Linux multi-thread application?
In a x86_64 Linux multi-thread application, if one thread executes an int 3 instruction, which thread will handle this signal (if all threads have registered SIGTRAP signal handlers)?
From Linux signal(7) manual section "Signal mask and pending signals":

A signal may be process-directed or thread-directed. (...). A thread-directed signal is one that is targeted at a specific
thread.  A signal may be thread-directed because it was generated
as a consequence of executing a specific machine-language
instruction that triggered a hardware exception (e.g., SIGSEGV
for an invalid memory access, or SIGFPE for a math error), or
because it was targeted at a specific thread using interfaces
such as tgkill(2) or pthread_kill(3).

I believe int 3 is a "machine-language instruction that triggered a hardware exception", so does this mean it is the same thread that will handle the SIGTRAP signal?
However, as stated in this SO answer:

(For the SIGTRAP signal raised by int 3,) A thread is found to deliver the signal to. The main thread is given first crack, but any thread can get it unless explicitly stated it doesn't want to.

It seems that the SIGTRAP is process-directed, which could be handled by any valid thread.
Moreover, if there is a tracer using ptrace on this multi-thread application, which thread will handle the signal if the tracer uses PTRACE_RESTART to inject this SIGTRAP signal back to the tracee?
